# Making Vector.Generic an instance of Functor (and other type-classes

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I run into trouble trying to make Vector.Generic.Vector an instance of other typeclasses (in my case - Functor).

I could settle for adding a Functor instance to Vector.Unboxed.Vector, but I couldn't figure out the syntax for that either.
My best take was to try something like:

```
instance (U.Unbox a, U.Unbox b) => Functor U.Vector where
    fmap = U.map
```

But the compiler (justfully) complained that 'a' and 'b' where nowhere after '=>'.
Can I even make this definition for Functor, as it assumes more restrictions on the types fmap is allowed to take?

Most stuff I found in SO was too advanced for me to figure out, so please be gentle :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think of the type of `fmap`:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

You are trying to add the constraint that `a` and `b` are both instances of `Unbox`. This is not doable because `fmap` is completely general while a map of an unboxed `Vector` is specific to instances `Unbox`.

It cannot be made a `Functor`.

Answer (score 4):

monadic is correct that this is currently not possible in haskell. However a new language feature currently in the ghc head development branch will make this possible.

The feature is called Constraint Kinds, and (among other features), allows you to add a indexed constraint to a class.  Instances of the class can decide what constraint will be needed. A default constraint can be supplied if the instance doesn't declare one.

For example, the Functor class could be rewritten like this:

```
class Functor m where
  type FunctorCtxt f a :: Constraint
  type FunctorCtxt f a = ()
  fmap :: (FunctorCtx f a, FunctorCtx f b) => f a -> f b
```

Existing instances such as for lists and `Maybe` would be unchanged - a default context of nothing is given (any type variable is acceptable). You could though add a new constraint for the Vector instance:

```
instance Functor U.Vector where
    type FunctorCtxt U.Vector a = U.Unbox a
    fmap = U.map
```

More details are at in this [Constraint Kinds for GHC blog post](http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/?p=127) and [KindFact GHC wiki post](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/KindFact).

Note that I don't have ghc head installed on my computer, so I wasn't able to test if this would actually work.

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting. however, I currently prefer not using the bleeding edge features (and, as monadic pointed out, I was trying to do something that collides with Functor's basic definition)

Comment: Absolutely, using features that are only present in a development branch is too risky, especially with a programming language (they could change the syntax/semantics before releasing it properly). It is something to look into in the future though.